# Select and crop face image from photo image (ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-image

I'm trying to get cropped image from photo. I have the following code that crop image that was got from ios face detection sdk:

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(CIFeature *)ciFeature image:(UIImage *)image {
    static int kMaxResolution = 640;

    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        } else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;

    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;
                default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                        format:@"Invalid image orientation"];
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    } else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *returnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return returnImage;
}
```

But how can I crop only face from the image (Like face image in box) because for now it changes original resolution of image?

Comment: @Aniton Kashpor, do you mean crop to a square image?

Comment: @aircraft yes, I do.

Comment: do you want crop the special position or the default square?

Comment: @aircraft only the place where the face is located.

Comment: OK, I know what you mean. and if this you must use 3tr library

Comment: how to crop face shape image  also move and scale cropview objective c  ?

Comment: @RamaniHitesh In my post you can see the example. You should change coordinate logic according your app.

Comment: Thank @antonkashpor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crop your image with more conveniently and more user-defined, I recommend you to use the RSKImageCropper, its github location is here:https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper

Because you want to crop the face's position, so the system's default method is not satisfy your requirement, you can learn from here:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010408-SW1

The Core Graphic's crop image method:`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`, is not easy to confirm the rect you want, because you for get the position of the face you should do a lot of work, the RSKImageCropper may be your convenient choise.